# User input string passed through a url

Tags: php, html

I am building a travel website where people can build up their travel itineraries.

There are pre built itineraries with cities and the users can click a button `"Add to Itinerary"` and this adds to the databse - this work fine.

I also want the opportunity for the user to add their own cities. The way I want to do this is by them clicking a button similar to `"Add to Itinerary"` but then they enter the name of this city and add to the list that way.

This is the code I have for the `"Add to Itinerary"` which is working.

```
<?php
if ( $_SESSION['user'] != "" ) {
  if ( in_array("Bangkok", $aray) ) { ?>
    <button class="buttonAddedItinerary">Already Added </button>
  <?php
  } else {
    ?>
    <a href="process.php?action=addtoItinirary&UCty=Bangkok">
      <button class="buttonAddItinerary">Add to Itinerary</button>
    </a>
  <?php
  }
}
?>
```

So basically I want when I click the button:
`<a href="process.php?action=addtoItinirary&UCty=USERINPUT"...`

Comment: I will not answer with a workaround as every php beginners guide could help you ... One thing that I could suggest to you is: never trust what user input into your fields ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is basic HTML form creation and processing. Any beginners PHP tutorial from the last 10+ years will show you how to do this. You will use `method="GET"` in your form tag.

Here's the tutorial from the PHP docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Comment: I have had a go at a form and using get, but its not working. Is this completely wrong?

    <?php session_start();
  if($_SESSION['user'] != ""){?> 
  
        <form action="process.php" method="get">
         Add Place: <input type="text"          'name="action=addtoItinirary&UCty=">                       
'        <input type="submit">
'        </form>

Comment: make the name of the text input just "UCty" and create a separate hidden field named "action" with a value of "addtoItinirary". And check your spelling of "Itinirary" to make sure it's consistent.

Answer (score 0):

You could use GET to pass user input and add it to the URL. So when when user input is present replace `process.php?action=addtoItinirary&UCty=Bangkok` with `process.php?action=addtoItinirary&UCty=UserCity`

Just sanitize the user input afterwards.